# How to set default height to containers and still be adjustable to responsive CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` container which contains an `img` with height of 311px.

The parent container follows the height of that image, but I want my container to have a height of 532px.

I have set the image CSS to `width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;` so that the image, even small, will still fill the container without any distortion, but I need to make the container to be responsive even when the screen gets smaller, and I've set the height to 532px so when the screen gets smaller, the height of div remains the same.

Is there any way to set a "default" height to `div` container, but adjusts when screen gets smaller?

here is the code html:

```
<style>
  .inside-img{
     object-fit: cover;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
  }

  .container{
     height: 532px;
  }
</style>

  <div class="container"><img class="inside-img" src="img.jpg"></div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe using `%` instead of `px`, would make it responsive. Or media queries.

Comment: @manjirosano I've tried giving the parent height of 30%, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Alright, just checked it out, and it makes sense. I think using media queries will be the answer here.

Comment: did you try height: auto; that is responsive. your width and height of your image are both 100% so whatever the image size is that will cover it 100%. are you trying to make the image to follow the container height? are you stretching it?what's the main goal?

Comment: @Crystal no, I want to set a default height for the container. if the container's height is set to 532px, the image will automatically resize based on the height of the container without distortions using the snippet above. but, if I resize the screen with the height set to static 532px, it remains to 532px when resized to smaller screen. I've tried giving it max-height property to 532px, but it's not following the height unfortunately.

Comment: @Crystal my main goal is to make the container default to 532px, at the same time make it adjustable when screen becomes smaller. I want to achieve this because the images uploaded will not be of same height, so making it cover the div makes it dynamic

Comment: @jn_lance since your goal is to make if flexible you have to put max-height in it. or auto. if you are talking about an image thats less than the container and you want it to get cover thats impossible having a 311px image height in a container of 532px meaning you need to stretch it. object-fit: contain to see the real size and cover to fit in the container.if the image is more than height that is possible but without distortion a small image will stretch no matter what you do to follow the container.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `min-height:300px;` this sets the minimum height for your container and can be adjusted